# MongoDB use modified array with $in operator

Tags: arrays, regex, mongodb

I have an array of id's and I want to find entries that match the id's inclusive a string.
For instance:
My array:

```
[ytn3z7ci2c6JQyKad, p3WxcY9Le79Eph8vM]
```

And I want to find all entries that match:

```
[ytn3z7ci2c6JQyKad-letter1, ytn3z7ci2c6JQyKad-letter2, p3WxcY9Le79Eph8vM-letter1, p3WxcY9Le79Eph8vM-letter2]
```

Is it possible to achieve this without modifying the array? Maybe use the $in operator in combination with $regex or $where?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify your question and include a specific example?  It's not clear what you're looking to do.

Comment: Please see my comment below. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question clearly.

Try using $or in conjuction with $regex

```
db.fun.find({$or:[{names:{$regex:arr[0]}}, {names:{$regex:arr[1]}} ]})
```

When array values are filtered in query, by default mongoDb loos for any value match

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I used it like this: `Letters.find({$or: [{name: {$regex: lettersArray}}]});`. It returns every single entry in the collection Letters. My problem is that I don't want to modify the array. To clarify this: `lettersArray[0] = ytn3z7ci2c6JQyKad`, `lettersArray[1] = p3WxcY9Le79Eph8vM`. Now I want to filter only the names in my Letters collection that match "ytn3z7ci2c6JQyKad-letter1" and "ytn3z7ci2c6JQyKad-letter2", without modifying the array (adding the string at the end of each entry).